# Multiple target environments and AWSGoogleSignIn

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, google-signin, aws-sdk-ios

Hello I am working with multiple AWS frameworks on an Ios project. The app is setup to target the specific backend environments though a dev and prod target in xcode.
This generally works fine though the use of constants and macros to use the different identity pools etc on build.

However I am now using AWSGoogleSignInProvider to link google sign-in and cognito. this requires a awsconfiguration.json file in the project which contains the google id and the cognito Id.

```
{
  "Version": "1.0",
  "CredentialsProvider": {
    "CognitoIdentity": {
      "Default": {
        "PoolId": "***",
        "Region": "***"
      }
    }
  },
  "IdentityManager": {
    "Default": {}
  },
  "GoogleSignIn": {
    "ClientId-iOS": "***",
    "Permissions": "email,profile,openid"
  }
}
```

Im unsure on how i can target dev/prod since i would need to use different pool ids depending on environments. Can't use two files with different names and targets since naming is "immutable" and cant use any macros in the Json file itself.

By looking at the AWS framework it seams there is no way to manually set any of these, and the shared instance gets the google id through the the Json file on instantiation or throws.

Comment: I understand your concern on supporting multiple awsconfiguration.json for the different environments. For snippets other than FacebbokSignIn and GoogleSignIn, this is possible by having Default and Custom. however, for FacebookSignIn and GoogleSignIn, different levels don't exist. I will take this as a feature request to the team.

Comment: @Karthikeyan this has also been requested here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/975